# Why does transforming a for-expression toDouble results in an unexpected sequence?

Tags: scala

I have been playing around with for expressions, and found myself dealing with an unexpected outcome. It's best that I would illustrate with an example:

```
  val someList = List(2.2, 3.4)

  val strangeDoubles = for {
    s <- someList.toString.replace(".", "")
  } yield s.toDouble

  println(strangeDoubles)

  // result: ArraySeq(76.0, 105.0, 115.0, 116.0, 40.0, 50.0, 50.0, 44.0, 32.0, 51.0, 52.0, 41.0)
```

My understanding is that a for expression with a single loop is turned into a `forEach`. However, I am not quite sure how the array ended having the following numbers. I would have expected the result to be something like: List(22.0, 34.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for-comprehension expands to

```
someList.toString.replace(".", "").map((s: Char) => s.toDouble)
```

substituting `someList.toString` we get

```
"List(2.2, 3.4)".replace(".", "").map((s: Char) => s.toDouble)
```

simplifying `"List(2.2, 3.4)".replace(".", "")` we get

```
"List(22, 34)".map((s: Char) => s.toDouble)
```

now mapping applies `(s: Char) => s.toDouble` to each character of the `String` so conceptually we have something like

```
Vector(
  'L'.toDouble,
  'i'.toDouble,
  's'.toDouble,
  't'.toDouble,
  '('.toDouble,
  '2'.toDouble,
  '2'.toDouble,
  ','.toDouble,
  ' '.toDouble,
  '3'.toDouble,
  '4'.toDouble,
  ')'.toDouble
)
```

which finally evaluates to

```
Vector(76.0, 105.0, 115.0, 116.0, 40.0, 50.0, 50.0, 44.0, 32.0, 51.0, 52.0, 41.0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You turned the **List** into a big **String** then you executed the `map` *(not `foreach`)* on each **Char** of the **String** and then you transformed each **Char** into a **Double** which is done by first transforming each character into its *ASCII* code.

I really do not understand why you turned the whole list into a **String**, maybe you wanted to do that to each element?
Like this:

```
val strangeDoubles = for {
  d <- someList
  s = d.toString.replace(".", "")
} yield s.toDouble
```

Or in this case, I would just call `map` directly instead.

```
someList.map { d =>
  d.toString.replace(".", "").toDouble
}
```